# how do I change the side bar content?

Tags: sidebar

As of now, my side bar is pretty standard:

How can I change it so that it shows tags, recent posts, etc...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go into your dashboard and click widgets to your left, and you will see all the tabs there you just drag and drop them to your right inside the panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to add something outside of the widgets, you can do so by editing the sidebar.php file of your theme too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using more (or even less) up-to-date theme it should support widgets.

See [Appearance Widgets SubPanel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Widgets_SubPanel) in Codex for overview.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: No Sidebar
Template By : Techbymak
Tempalte designed By : Akshay Makadiya
URL : http://techbymak.com
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div style=”width:850px !important;”>
<?php the_content(‘
Read More »</p>’); ?>
<?php edit_post_link(‘Update this post’, ‘<p>’, ‘</p>’); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e(‘ooops!! , No match found’); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I think this is useful to you.
Source : http://techbymak.com/create-blank-wordpress-page-with-no-sidebar-no-footer-no-header.html

Comment: This is invalid PHP: do not use curly quotes. And **please** add an explanation: why would that solve the problem?